# How do I listen for the softkey inside the editText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

How do I listen for the softkey inside the editText?

edit: Can I get onKeydown and onKeyUp events? When i am entering any data inside the edittext?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. I had posted this question out of curiosity from a particular requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Can you be more specific with your question?

If you want to detect when the user type something, you should use onTextChanged  :

```
etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { 
     public void  afterTextChanged (Editable s){ 
          Log.d("seachScreen", "afterTextChanged"); 
     } 
     public void  beforeTextChanged  (CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){ 
          Log.d("seachScreen", "beforeTextChanged"); 
     } 
     public void  onTextChanged  (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { 
          Log.d("seachScreen", "onTextChanged"); 
     }
```

Comment: I mean if I am in EditText and I press any thing on the softkey in android emulator then how will i get notified? like key events. please note this is not from hard keyboard but from virtual or softkey board

Comment: thanks I am getting the callback here, but can i get key events also like this like which key is pressed?

Comment: I guess you can guet the edittext value by getText() and get last caracter, but there is for sure something better.

Comment: public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 
  if (s.length > 0) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
      char lastCharacter = s.charAt(s.length() - 1); 
      }
  }

Comment: i think I am still not clear with my question. I am trying to get the keydown and key up event in the edittext. Is this possible to get it. I am not looking for last character in the edittext.

Comment: Houps.. I understand now... Really sorry for my answer.